# [Python]How to deal with a string ending with one backslash?

Tags: python, string, escaping, backslash

I'm getting some content from Twitter API, and I have a little problem, indeed I sometimes get a tweet ending with only one backslash.
More precisely, I'm using simplejson to parse Twitter stream.

How can I escape this backslash ?

From what I have read, such raw string shouldn't exist ...
Even if I add one backslash (with two in fact) I still get an error as I suspected (since I have a odd number of backslashes)

Any idea ?
I can just forget about these tweets too, but I'm still curious about that.

Thanks : )

Comment: A sample of the response you're getting that's causing the problem would help.

Comment: tzot put it right, `r"no\problem" + "\\"` is a good way to get: no\problem\

Answer (score 1):

Prepending the string with `r` (stands for "raw") will escape all characters inside the string. For example:

`print r'\b\n\\'`

will output

`\b\n\\`

Have I understood the question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking a method similar to [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) in PHP. So, here you go:

[Python version of PHP's stripslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454/python-version-of-phps-stripslashes)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using raw strings by prepending an `r` (so nothing has to be escaped) to the string or [re.escape()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape).

I'm not really sure what you need considering I haven't seen the text of the response. If none of the methods you come up with on your own or get from here work, you may have to forget about those tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you update your question and come back with a real problem, I'm asserting that you don't have an issue except confusion.

You get the string from the Tweeter API, ergo the string does not show up in your *code*. “Raw strings” exist only in your code, and it is “raw strings” in code that can't end in a backslash.

Consider this:

```
def some_obscure_api():
    "This exists in a library, so you don't know what it does"
    return r"hello" + "\\" # addition just for fun

my_string = some_obscure_api()
print(my_string)
```

See? `my_string` happily ends in a backslash and your code couldn't care less.