# Str.replace('\\', '') not working for backslashes

Tags: python, string

I want to remove backslashes and I've read that you can use

```
Str.replace('\\', '')
```

I've also tried

```
re.sub(r'\\', '',text)
```

However both do not work for me. I'm wondering if someone can help me figure out what is wrong.

```
text = ['with General Atlantic, Newman\'s Own Foundation, The Pershing Square Foundation, Rockefeller Philanthropy Advisors, and Echoing Green announced a three-year partnership which will invest']
text.replace('\\','')
```

I still get 'Newman\'s Own Foundation'

To clarify:
 I'm attempting to get words with Consecutive words where first letters are capitalized, as in proper nouns. The backslash messes up this regex from capturing Newman's Own. So it seems like removing the backslash isn't the best idea? r'\b(?

I'm getting the backslashes when I print the text in ipython notebook

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454/python-version-of-phps-stripslashes

Comment: You don't have any backslashes in that text. You have an escaped apostrophe. If you `print(text[0])` you'll see the apostrophe without the backslash

Comment: You are confusing the Python literal string representation with the value. Python echos the value to you *with explicit escapes* so you can paste it into the interpreter without syntax errors and ASCII-safe.

Comment: Hi, thank you! But if I wanted to edit the text, how would I do so? I'm processing the text, and it's getting messed up because the backslash is messing up my regex. I keep getting Newman versus Newman's Own.

Comment: @user3314418: perhaps you want to ask **that** question then; what problem are you having with your regular expression?

Comment: I see, I'll post that question then. I'm attempting to get words with Consecutive words where first letters are capitalized, as in proper nouns. The backslash messes up this regex from capturing Newman's Own. So it seems like removing the backslash isn't the best idea? r'\b(?<!")(?!The|As|About|Said|With|For|And|In|On|Through|Unlike|By)([A-Z][A-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])+(?:\s[A-Z][A-z]+)+)\b'

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add that?

Comment: And that regular expression doesn't touch upon quotes at all. If you want to include quotes in matches you need to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The text does not contain a backslash to remove. The backslash present in text actually escapes the apostrophe.

If you try `print text[0]` , you will get an output as:

`with General Atlantic, Newman's Own Foundation, The Pershing Square Foundation, Rockefeller Philanthropy Advisors, and Echoing Green announced a three-year partnership which will invest`

Which has no backslash.

The reason you get the backslash is *probably* because it returns the representation. [ *probably* since even python shell does not return the backslash unless you explicitly call the `repr(text[0])` function, atleast not in your case.  ].

Incase you want to remove that escaping backslash from the representation and convert it back to a string ( though I find it pointless to do so ) you can try this:

`repr(text[0]).replace('\\','')[1:-1]`

EDIT: When working with regex convert your r'some text' to str(r'some text'). That should work.

Comment: The shell uses `repr()` when echoing the output of expressions. So if you use `>>> text` `repr()` is used unless the expression returned `None`.

Comment: Also, the python container types use `repr()` on the contents. `text[0]` is in a list, so `text` would use `[repr(text[0]), repr(text[1]), ...]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True but when I tried `text[0]` in Python shell I did not find any backlash. Why is that so?

Comment: Python is smart and'll use double quotes if it can to avoid having to quote. Create a value with *both* quote types: `'She\'s fond of saying "Hello"'`.

Comment: Exactly! so user3314418 should never have got 'Newman\'s Own Foundation' except when explicitly calling repr() right?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using the code you named above, and it doesn' tseem to work...

Comment: @rvraghav93: clearly we are not getting the full picture, which is why people are voting to close.

Comment: @user3314418 Tell us where (as in shell or when using print etc ..) you get the back slash so we can help you out.

Comment: I'm getting the backslashes when I print the text in ipython notebook

Comment: replicate my code in your ipython notebook and comment back the result
`text = ['hello\'foo']` then `print text[0]`

Comment: Hm, that works now with text[0] text = ['hello\'foo']
repr(text[0]).replace('\\','')[1:-1]
#hello'foo but it doesn't seem to work with my text...

Comment: text = [' was released by the U.S. Agency for International Development (USAID):rnrnThis week, the U.S. Agency for International Development (USAID), with General Atlantic, Newman\'s Own Foundation']
repr(text).replace('\\','')[1:-1] turns out '" released by the U.S. Agency for International Development (USAID):rnrnThis week, the U.S. Agency for International Development (USAID), with General Atlantic, Newman\'s Own Foundation"'

Comment: I guess you are using the %r format which uses representation of the string as Martijn pointed out.

Comment: So how do I deal with this issue?

Comment: try str(r'some random string') instead...

Comment: try str(r'some random string) as my text?

Comment: Yes. try `text[0] = str(text[0])` then try `print text[0]`.

Comment: same thing unfortunately: str(doclist[20]).replace('\\','') still gets me backslashes. doclist[20] is just a piece of text